# How to ensure the string is full of spaces for a given length?

Tags: c, string, validation, null, strlen

I have a bunch of strings that I need to verify if these have all spaces.

I can do `strlen(trim(strct.data)) > 0`.

But, it's **not null terminated**, but the *length is known*.

i.e. if `strct.len` is 5 then I need to verify if `strct.data` has spaces for 5 chars. 6th char is not guaranteed to be null. I have an array of `strct` each of which can have different length of data to be validated for spaces.

I tried `strnlen(trim(strct.data))` and later realized it didn't fix anything as the trim already removed all spaces.

Any ideas other than the obvious looping over each character of `strct.data` (my last option if there is no other go)?

note: trim is a userdefined function I use to remove leading and trailing spaces. It doesn't stop until the NULL too. I am looking for a way to handle both.

Comment: How does `trim()` know when to stop if the `data` is not `NUL` terminated?

Comment: Is there a *reason* you are not using NULL terminated strings? Without that, you need custom code to handle any "string" operations, and pass the whole structure or both "string" and length.

Comment: Can't you change trim to return the number of spaces removed? Trim has to walk the string anyway.

Comment: @crashmstr I do not have control over that part. I receive only the structure for validation.

Comment: @Henno it would keep walking and the 6th character could be a space too.. :(

Comment: @San So your custom trim is not honoring the len of your string?!? I don't get it.

Comment: @Henno that is part of the existing one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to ensure the string is full of spaces for a given length?

step 1:

```
  char buf[MAX_SIZE];
  sprintf(buf,"%*s",MAX_SIZE-1,"");  //fill buffer with spaces
```

---

step 2:

Now use `strncmp()` compare strct.len number of character of  `strct.data` character array with `buf`

```
if(strncmp(strct.data ,buf ,strct.len) ==0)
  {
   //all are spaces
  }
```

You need not to repeat step1.

---

Another solution jxh suggested you can also use `memset()` instead of `sprintf()`

```
  memset(buf, ' ', sizeof buf); //fill buf with all spaces
```

You need do this once, next time onwards you need not do this.

---

You can also use VLA.

declaring `char buf[strct.len]`;

but you need to use memset each time.

Comment: You can use `memset()` on the buffer, and you can use VLA to do `char buf[strct.len]`, and use `memcmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best is doing the looping yourself:

```
for(int i=0; i<strct.len; ++i) {
  if(strct[i] != ' ') {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Comment: As I said, it's the one I'd choose if there is no other better way.

Comment: Your trim has to iterate over the string anyway. Probably you have the number you need in there already.

Comment: This should work if a new func that takes care of trimming with `strct.len`. As you've suggested it'll have the number already.

Answer (score 1):

As the character array is not null terminated, it is not a *string*.
But let's not quibble on that point and make a fast routine for large arrays.

```
IsCharArrayAllSpace(const char *p, size_t Length) {
  if (Length < 1) return 1;  // TBD: decide how to handle the zero-length case
  return (p[0] == ' ') && (memcmp(p, &p[1], Length-1) == 0);
}
```